# Cant create customer in Stripe after getting token

Tags: php, stripe-payments

After following the "Using Checkout and PHP" documentation line for line I have everything working except the last part.

My code reads like this

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  'email' => 'customer@example.com',
  'source'  => $token
));

echo '<h1>Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';
?>
```

Everything works great I can do a var_dump on the token and see that is working fine, my issue is the customer array. I have tried using Stripe_Customer instead of \Stripe\Customer but it still isn't working.

A few things I might have to note is I downloaded the files manually and I'm using mamp but I dont think thats the problem as I'm able to receive tokens, it just stops working as soon as I add the customer array.

Here is my config.php file

```
<?php
require_once('../stripe/init.php');

$stripe = array(
 "secret_key"      => "test",
 "publishable_key" => test"
);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

Comment: I presume you are setting your API key somewhere?

Comment: @amdouglas yea its in config.php

Comment: Okay, I thought it would have to be because you're getting tokens. I know that when you create a customer, the card number is validated—what are you using as a test card number?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, it was a TLS update problem. After updating MAMP everything worked.